# How to calculate heat loss of a building using thermal inertia?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I need to calculate the amount of heat that is lost in an hour. I know the temperature of the building the (effective) temperature of the outside  and the thermal inertia of the building.
The building is not necessarily actualy cooling down since heating is a thing.

Is there a formula to calculate this?
does it make it easier if you assume that there is no heating? or that the temperature is constant?

My endgoal with this question is calculating the heat capacity of the building. I have data of the temperature inside and data of the weather of several years to do this.

Comment: Does the building have windows and doors?  Is the sun shining on it, and if so, at what time of day?  Is the wind blowing, and if so, at what velocity?  Is it raining?  Are there people and other heat generating items inside the buillding?  This is not an easy question to answer when all variables are specified, and it is impossible to answer without that specification.

Comment: I can pick data from a time where the answer to all of these questions is no

Comment: There are many factors involved in calculating the losses of a building, see for example :https://www.h2xengineering.com/blogs/calculating-heat-loss-simple-understandable-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The rate of heat energy loss, i.e. the **heat flux**, of an object is described by [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law):

$$\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}=-hA[T(t)-T_{\infty}]$$

where:

- $\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}$ is the heat flux
- $T(t)$ is the temperature of the object in time $t$ and $T_{\infty}$ the temperature of the surroundings
- $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient and $A$ the surface area exposed to the surroundings.

Note that this law relies on *lumped thermal analysis*, which means the temperature of the object $T(t)$ is uniform in space, with no spatial temperature gradients. For large objects like buildings that is of course not very realistic.

> Does it make it easier if you assume that there is no heating? Or that
> the temperature is constant?

These are two distinct cases:

- The latter case allows direct calculation of the heat flux, using the formula above.
- For the former case, $T(t)$ will evolve in time, which can be seen by re-writing the heat flux:

$$mc_p\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=-hA[T(t)-T_{\infty}]$$

where $m$ is the object's mass and $c_p$ its specific heat capacity.

This is an easy differential equation which solves to:

$$T(t)=T_{\infty}-(T_{\infty}-T_0)\exp\Big(-\frac{t}{\tau}\Big)$$

where $T_0$ is the initial temperature ($t=0$) of the object and $\tau$ is the *characteristic time*:

$$\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{h A}{m c_p}$$

---

A temperature v. time plot of:

$$\ln\Big(\frac{T(t)-T_{\infty}}{T_0-T_{\infty}}\Big)=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$

should yield a straight line with $\frac{1}{\tau}$ as the gradient. If $m$ and $c_p$ are known then $hA$ can be calculated from that.

[image: Ln theta graph]

In the figure above,

$$\ln \Theta=\ln\Big(\frac{T(t)-T_{\infty}}{T_0-T_{\infty}}\Big)$$

Carry out linear regression on the data points (little circles) to find $1/\tau$.

Comment: if I understand this correctly I can fill in al the temperatures in the second to last formula to calculate τ and then use that in combination with hA to calculate mcp which is the heat capacity of the entire building. Which is what i was trying to calculate in the first place. probably should have mentioned that. If thats all correct then is there a way to calculate hA using temperature data?

Comment: Hi. I've answered that question above (below the page break).